# Perl / BerkelyDB @INC problems trying to install Amavisd-new (CentOS)

Tags: centos, email, perl, amavis

I'm trying to follow this guide here to install Amavis, SpamAssassin + ClamAV...

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Amavisd

Things mostly went well but Amavisd would not start...

```
# service amavisd start
Starting Mail Virus Scanner (amavisd): ERROR: MISSING REQUIRED BASIC MODULES:
  Unix::Syslog
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/amavisd line 237.
                                                   [FAILED]
```

I installed Unix Syslog at the perl command line...

```
# perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan[1]> install Unix::Syslog
```

But this threw up an error for the path to the BerkeleyDB...

```
# service amavisd start
Starting Mail Virus Scanner (amavisd): Problem in Amavis::DB or Amavis::DB::SNMP code: Can't locate BerkeleyDB.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at (eval 82) line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 82) line 19.
```

The BerkeleyDB files for my distro are installed in...

```
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/
```

I did some reading and it seems changing @INC is not so easy - I would need to add "use lib" directly to the perl scripts - modifying Amavis/BerkeleyDB doesn't seem the sensible or correct approach. So I tried moving the BerkelyDB files to...

```
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
```

Which is in the @INC path. This nearly worked but now I get...

```
# service amavisd start
Starting Mail Virus Scanner (amavisd): /usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/BerkeleyDB/BerkeleyDB.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Tstack_sp_ptr
                                                       [FAILED]
```

I'm sure I'm going the wrong route here. I'm a perl n00b but it seems odd that yum installs places the BerkeleyDB files in a place that perl cant access them. Hoping someone can cut through my mess.

Many thanks!